# Use of OR in activate framework queries

Tags: scala

Querying 'AND' sounds simple on activate framework, the ',' makes the 'AND' job

```
transactional {
    val personList2 = allWhere[NaturalPerson](_.name :== "Test", _.motherName :== "Mother")
}
```

I'm wondering how OR is made. An example would be nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use OR with allWhere. Note that you have to use parenthesis.

```
allWhere[NaturalPerson](p => (p.name :== "Test") :|| (p.motherName :== "Mother"))
```

Or you can use the complete query form:

```
query {
    (p: NaturalPerson) => where((p.name :== "Test") :|| (p.motherName :== "Mother")) select(p)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the test suite that comes with the framework. Here is an example test taken from [`QuerySpecs.scala`](https://github.com/fwbrasil/activate/blob/master/activate-tests/src/test/scala/net/fwbrasil/activate/statement/query/QuerySpecs.scala):

```
"support query with or" in {
  activateTest(
    (step: StepExecutor) => {
      import step.ctx._
      step {
        newFullActivateTestEntity
        newEmptyActivateTestEntity
      }
      step {
        query {
          (e: ActivateTestEntity) =>
            where(    (e.booleanValue :== true)
                  :|| (e.booleanValue :== false)
                  :|| (e.booleanValue isNull)) select (e)
        }.size must beEqualTo(3)

        query {
          (e: ActivateTestEntity) =>
            where(     (e.booleanValue :== true)
                   :|| (e.charValue :== fullCharValue)) select (e)
        }.size must beEqualTo(1)
      }
    })
}
```